# "posting" an image in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently use this little line of code to "post" messages.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    o.html(o.html() + "Username:<br>" + msg[r] + "<br><hr>") 
}, 7000);
```

It works great, it posts messages from an array, ads some styling.

But right now when it posts a message it looks like:

```
Username:
messagehere

<hr>
```

What I want is the code to post an image as well, before the message and username. Like as you would see on facebook when chatting with someone, commenting something etc.

I tried just putting a `+<img src="" class=""/>` in front of it but that did nothing. The whole code suddenly stopped working.

So right now I am looking for the correct way of doing this, id like to add an class to it, so I can style the whole thing correctly with css (having the avatar in front of the message and username, like explained earlier)

If someone could help me find the correct way, that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Wherever you got that actual script from, you should have inquired there first ;). Put the `img` code in a string: `+ '<img src="" class=""/>'`

Comment: Escape your quotes `"<img src=\"" + imageSrc[r] + "\" alt=\"\"/>Username:<br>" + ...`, or wrap it with single quotes, as hj potter suggested (Better readability).

Comment: `+ "<img src="images/avatar.jpg" class="chat_avatar">"` unfortunately also breaks the code.

Comment: @Snowlav didn't you read our comments? :) Your HTML quotes are breaking your JS quotes. Do this: `+ '<img src="images/avatar.jpg" class="chat_avatar">'` with single quotes

Comment: wow I never realized single quotes made a difference, silly me. Thanks guys :)

Comment: It's not really a _difference_ (you could switch them all in your code), it's more that if you start a string with `"`, it will think the next one is the end of the string and error out when it sees the next one. Same goes for single quotes. So when possible, use the opposite (eg: `"st'ring"`), or escape them with a backslash (eg: `"st\"ring"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wrap the `img` tag in quotes. It's erroring because without the quotes, your browser thinks it's a variable or function instead of a string literal.

```
+ '<img src="" class=""/>'
```

Also, you should use the .append() function instead of doing .html(.html() + ...)

```
o.append("Username:<br>" + msg[r] + "<br><hr>" + "<img src='' class='' />");
```